# Camel startupOrder for route is not working with File component

Tags: apache-camel

I want to start file reading route after executing some logic, so i used startupOrder. But as soon as camel initilized, file component started polling without waiting for other route to complete execution.

Routes:

```
 <route id="test" startupOrder="1">
    <from uri="timer:foo?period=1000&amp;repeatCount=1" />
    <bean method="checkLogic" ref="serviceProcessor" />
```

```
<route id="readconfigfile" >
      <from uri="file:{{config.ConfigPath}}?recursive={{config.ConfigRecursiveRead}}&amp;noop=true&amp;consumer.delay={{config.ConfigFileReadGap}}"/>
      <bean method="configRead(${body},&#39;Config&#39;)" ref="ConfigReader"/>
```

Please help here.

Comment: see controlbus how to start a route from a route, and then mark the 2nd route to not auto start.

Comment: i am using ver 2.10. Can't use controlbus.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the route `readconfigfile` to `autoStartup=false`

```
<route id="readconfigfile" autoStartup="false">
```

... and then from your bean `serviceProcessor` then inject `CamelContext` and use its api to start that route, eg

```
camelContext.startRoute("readconfigfile");
```

when you are done with the bean code, and ready to start  that route.

Comment: But why the startupOrder doesn't work here? There is nothing in the documentation about this exception. Is it known property of file reading routes or a bug or does it have some logic explanation that I cannot see? Thnx. I'm using version 2.17.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set startupOrder=2 in the second route like the example below:

```
<route startupOrder="1">
    <from uri="seda:foo"/>
    <to uri="mock:result"/>
</route>

<route startupOrder="2">
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <to uri="seda:foo"/>
</route>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Also, unordered root should start only after ordered route executes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this doesn't work, its taken straight from the documentation. http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html

Comment: I have already tried that but as soon as camel initializes, file component starts polling. I had introduced delay in route with startupOrder 1 just to see if other starts only after first route completes the execution but thats not happening.

Comment: In that case probably best to look at what Claus said but its a bit difficult since you are on an older version and use the xml dsl. At least in java perhaps you could have introduced some sort of sleep mechanism.  Alternatively change your design so that once the route 1 is finished then trigger route 2 via a "to" by sending some dummy data which you discard.

Comment: I guess i will have to go with Clauss's suggestion. Thanks for your help.